# Having some issues with uploading images using multer with nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I am using multer to upload images into a folder in my project. But there is no error showing when using multer and i can't figure out what was the problem. It works perfectly with a basic new project but in my project it is not working

**here is the code of the api to upload the image**

```
router.post('/add-product-1', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);
  console.log('llllllllllllllllll');
  res.send('File uploaded!');
});
```

here req.file is empty but i was specified the enctype=multipart/form-data

**here is the form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>upload images</h2>
 
    <form action="/admin/add-product-1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**and this is the code i used for multer**

```
const multer=require("multer");
const path=require('path')
const storage=multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,"Images");
    },
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        console.log(file);
        cb(null,Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})
const upload=multer({
    storage:storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 // 5 MB
      },
    // dest:'Images'
});

module.exports={upload}
```

and i imported in the api page like
`let {upload} = require('../middlewares/multer');` 
i am looking for what's wrong with this code and still i can't figure out if anyone can correct it. it will be very helpful for me

Comment: How is it not working? You should probably add that to your answer, or specify that you need general help on how to debug an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the path for a destination to store the image in `diskStorage`.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./public/uploads",
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});
```

now the image is stored in `public/uploads` directory.